# Can I define a String.prototype method in an external file and import it where I need it?

Tags: typescript

What I'm looking to do I thought would be easy, but apparently history has proven otherwise...

This is what I want to do (for example)...

```
// file1.ts
interface String {
    lastChar(): string
}
String.prototype.lastChar = function(): string {
    return this.substr(-1);
}
```

.

```
// file2.ts
import * from './file1.ts'

let x = 'test';
let y = x.lastChar();
// y = "t";
```

I'd like to store the prototype method in some outside file and then import it in the few files that I need it. Currently I have a giant String.prototype method defined at the top of the few files that need the method and I'd like to get it out of there.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the following code does the thing you need:

file1.ts

```
interface String
{ 
    lastChar: () => string;
}

String.prototype.lastChar = function(): string {
    return this.substr(-1);
};
```

file2.ts:

```
import "./file1";

let s: String = "123";
console.log(s.lastChar()); //outputs 3
```

Hope it helps.